# Does Power Apps have the ability to write an If(foo in {bar1, bar2, bar3}){...} expression?

Tags: if-statement, powerapps

Suppose that I'm handling the `Visible` property of a form and I only want three users to see it. Suppose that I have their IDs (1234, 12345, and 123456) and that `User.ID` is a way to extract that. I want to write an expression like `if(User.ID in {1234, 12345, 123456}, true, false)`. Does Power Apps support this concept in any way? I could of course write the equivalent `switch` or `User.ID = 1234 || User.ID = 12345 || User.ID = 123456` trick, but I'm hoping to be able to use an ad-hoc collection inside an `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/operators#in-and-exactin-operators) in the language:

```
Form.Visible ==> User.ID in [1234, 12345, 123456]
```

Comment: Is there a documentation link for your usage of square brackets?

Comment: It is used to define a table. You can see more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-tables#table